# Variable as expression - advanced calculator

Tags: php

Let's consider following code:

```
/**
 * @param  string $exp  expression
 * @param  number $var1
 * @param  number $var2 
 * @return json
 */
  public function calculate($exp, $var1, $var2) {}
```

What is the quickest and most elegant way to handle this calculate function?

Am I restricted to the 'switch'? Or is it possible to somehow implement the

```
$var1 . $exp . $var2
```

Which will result in the sum instead of string?

Did some heavy research on that, it's really trivial problem but it got me thinking for an few hours now.

Comment: Can you give an example or what you would like entering into the function and what you would expect from it?

Comment: of course:
('+',3,5) => 8
('-',5,2) => 3
('/',2,2) => 1

Comment: 1. I think the switch is ok here because of the limit in operator choices
2. That sounds like a homework

Comment: Something like: https://eval.in/188927 ?

Comment: I'm not okay with switch. I was looking for more 'versiable' solution, "one liner" would be best. Besically, let's say I currently have the switch for '+, -, and /' I need to add '*, &&, %, ||' without adding additional cases to the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, use the following logic;

```
<?php

function c($e, $a, $b) {
   $e = create_function("", "return (" . $a . $e . $b . ");" );
   return 0 +  $e();
}

echo c("+", 1, 2);
```

#### [Live Preview](https://eval.in/188927)

`create_function` creates an [anonymous](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) [lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)-style function, which is created at run time and not held in memory. It allows for more flexibility than `switch`, as you won't have to keep adding `case` statements for the operator, **but** it does an internal `eval()`, so you'd need to do some data validation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval()` this would be the most simplest, however, it is also a very dangerous function, so if you were to use it you would have to implement some validation that checks to make sure that only the correct operators are passed which would essentially make it not worth using.

I would just stick to using a switch statement:

```
public function calculate($exp, $var1, $var2) {
    switch($char) {
        case '=': return $var1 = $var2;
        case '*': return $var1 * $var2;
        case '+': return $var1 + $var2;
        case '-': return $var1 - $var2;
    }
}
```